# Best practice for handling null prop when accessing prop attribute

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React component that I pass a prop that I use to set the initial state of the component as such:

```
class ContactForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    const { contact } = this.props
    const { name, position, email, phone_number } = contact

    this.state = {
      name: name,
      position: position,
      email: email,
      phone_number: phone_number
    }
  }
}
```

However, the contact prop that I pass could possibly be null. What is the best way to handle a null prop when I am trying to access the prop attributes? I can have an if statement that checks whether or not contact is null, and set the state as such, like this:

```
if (contact) {
  const { name, position, email, phone_number } = contact

  this.state = {
    name: name,
    position: position,
    email: email,
    phone_number: phone_number
  }
} else {
  this.state = {
    name: '',
    position: '',
    email: '',
    phone_number: ''
  }
}
```

But I was wondering if there is a better approach

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can default `contact` to an empty object, and give the other values empty strings as default:

```
class ContactForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    // Only undefined values can be given default values when destructuring,
    // so it needs to be written like this
    const contact = this.props.contact || {}
    const { name = '', position = '', email = '', phone_number = '' } = contact

    this.state = {
      name,
      position,
      email,
      phone_number
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe that the best option in this case is use defaultProps from React Component. Maybe this can help you:

```
class ContactForm extends React.Component {
 // your component code
}
ContactForm.defaultProps = {
  name: '',
  position: '',
  email: '',
  phone_number: '',
};
```

I strongly recommend you to use prop-types too, then you can define a standard type for each Prop that you expect to receive

If you used Create React App CLI, just import it:

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
```

And before your defaultProps write something like:

```
ContactForm.propTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string,
  position: PropTypes.string,
  phone_number: PropTypes.number,
  ...
}
```

You should use static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) to set your new State by props received. Try also:

```
class ContactForm extends React.Component {
 static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
   // Checking if props.contact exist
   if (props.contact) return {...contact}
 }
}
```

getDerivedStateFromProps should return an object that will represent the new state of component.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following way to define your `ContactForm` component.

```
class ContactForm extends React.Component {

    //your default state  
    state = {
        name: '',
        position: '',
        email: '',
        phone_number: ''
    };

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {...this.state,...props.contact};
    }

    render(){

    }
}
```

this way you have your default state and you directly use all the props passed from contact to your state.